# Difference between "submitted" and "finished" transactions in Substrate blockchain framework?

Tags: blockchain, substrate

I run a private network of 6 nodes using substrate **node-template v3.0.0**. During tests, I noticed a difference between "submitted" and "finished" transactions when **sending at a constant transaction rate** to the blockchain.

I have sent valid transactions ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qwyl.png)) and there is very big difference between "submitted" and "finished" transactions, what does "submitted" and "finished" transactions actually mean ?

Prometheus queries are respectively:

- `substrate_sub_txpool_submitted_transactions`
- `substrate_sub_txpool_validations_finished`

Also there aren't any invalid transactions.

[image: In picture here]

Comment: are you using https://github.com/paritytech/sub-flood to do this?
you are really hammering your nodes, but how exactly? Meaning what nodes receive the transactions? are you rotating?

Comment: I use a similar benchmark model: initialize accounts, then round-robin on them by tracking the nonce to prevent outdated and other errors. The WebSockets are load-balanced with an ingress controller (the nodes are on a cloud using Kubernetes): so difficult to know precisely how the client WebSockets requests are attributed to each node (anyhow, I have not more than 10 WebSockets open). The question stays the same, what is the difference between the two elements? How can it be that the nodes don't share the same number of finished transactions?

Comment: Are all nodes block producers (authorities in AuRa)? It is possible that transactions are being validated and then not included in blocks as they are not gossiped to the block producer. I would expect your load balancing being opaque to what node is targeted might make this difficult to assess directly. Here is more details on tx processing: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/learn-substrate/tx-pool#transaction-lifecycle

Comment: further you can inspect the logic to get a sense of what produces these metrics: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/client/transaction-pool/src --- metrics fol the pool and the pool's API are distinct here in `metrics.rs`

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a better look at the code. If I will understand it correctly I'll post an answer here.